# Can you convert file contents to a file object?

Tags: python, string, file, file-io

I have a function the expects a file object, simplified example:

```
def process(fd):
    print fd.read()
```

which would normally be called as:

```
fd = open('myfile', mode='r')
process(fd)
```

I can't change this function, and I already have the contents of the file in memory. Is there any way to `convert` the file contents into a file object without writing it to disk so I could do something like this:

```
contents = 'The quick brown file'
fd = convert(contents) # ??
process(fd)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html):

> This module implements a file-like class, StringIO, that reads and
>   writes a string buffer (also known as memory files).

```
from StringIO import StringIO

def process(fd):
    print fd.read()

contents = 'The quick brown file'

buffer = StringIO()
buffer.write(contents)
buffer.seek(0)

process(buffer)  # prints "The quick brown file"
```

Note that in Python 3 it was moved into [io](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/io.html#io.StringIO) package - you should use `from io import StringIO` instead of `from StringIO import StringIO`.

Comment: You may want to note that in Python 3, it has been moved into the `io` module.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works if you are content with a 'file-like object', of which objects of the `StringIO` class are only a special case. However, instances of the `StringIO` class are *not* 'file objects' in the strict sense used in Python (i.e. the same type as something returned by the built-in `open` function).

For example, `StringIO` objects [have no `fileno` method](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/StringIO.py), with the method deliberately being omitted:

> fileno() is left unimplemented so that code which uses it triggers
>     an exception early.

There are several reasons why one might a strict 'file object' and not just a 'file-like object'. As [the above](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/StringIO.py) says,

> Using a real file is often faster (but less convenient).

Another reason is that 'file-like' objects (like those of the `StringIO` class) can *not* be used as the argument for the `stdin` argument of `create_subprocess_exec` of `asyncio.subprocess`, which is the use case I had in mind when I found this question on Google. This is because, in Python 3.7, on line 1324 of `subprocess.py` (defining the `subprocess` module, which `asyncio.subprocess` uses), the `_get_handles` method attempts to define the variable `p2cread = stdin.fileno()`, which clearly will only work if `stdin` has a `fileno` method in the first place. Thus the distinction between a true 'file object' and a 'file-like object' (like instances of the `StringIO` class) is not just pointless pedantry.

The following is not intended to be an ideal solution, but worked for my purposes:

```
def string_to_file(string):
    file_object = open('temporary_file.temporary', 'w')
    file_object.write(string)
    file_object.flush()
    return file_object
```

On the other hand it ***doesn't*** work for your purposes because it writes to disk. This might work instead then:

```
def string_to_file(string):
    import tempfile
    file_like_object = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    file_like_object.write(string.encode())
    file_like_object.flush()
    return file_like_object
```

Both work for passing to `create_subprocess_exec`.